# PHP Call Class Variable With String and Array

Tags: php, variables

Normally, you can set a php variable to call a function using a string. For example:

```
$myVariable = 'myClassVariable';
$this->$myVariable; // works!
```

However, how do I pass a string when there is an array involved? (refer below)

```
$this->someVariable['my_field']; // works
$callName = 'someVariable["my_field"]';
$this->$callName; // doesn't work
```

I've also tried `$callName = ${'someVariable["my_field"]'}` and that doesn't work either.

Comment: 2 separate examples above, I've reworded to make more clear the samples.

Comment: `$callName = $someVariable["my_field"];`

Comment: Nope - that gives an illegal string offset error.. :s

Comment: Nothing in your code samples seems to have anything to do with functions. I think I understand what you're trying, but that's not how PHP works. A string containing square brackets can't then be used to deference array items (without using eval, but then you've just got further problems)

Answer (score 0):

You are treating the array as a string. That will never work. An [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) can never be a [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and vice versa.

This will call the function `someFunction` and return `Foo`.

```
$this->someVariable['my_field'] = 'someFunction';
$this->{$this->someVariable["my_field"]}();

public function someFunction() {
    return 'Foo';
}
```